# Footnotes in a table are not working (ConText)

Tags: tables, context

I am trying to put a footnote in a table header but the footnote does not appear. Below is some example code showing the issue:

```
\starttext


This is a sentence.

This one has a footnote\footnote{a footnote}

\bTABLE
%
% IMPORTANT: use \bTH ... \eTH to enclose the head|next cells
\bTABLEhead
\bTR
\bTH   \eTH
\bTH  Difference\footnote{this footnote does not appear}\eTH
\eTR
\eTABLEhead

%
% the table body (main part)
%
\bTABLEbody
\bTR 
\bTD Exchange Rates \eTD 
\bTD 3.0\% \eTD 
\eTR 
\bTR 
\bTD Hedging Costs \eTD 
\bTD 2.1\% \eTD 
\eTR 

\eTABLEbody

\bTABLEfoot
\bTR 
\bTD Total \eTD 
\bTD xxx\% \eTD 
\eTR 
\eTABLEfoot

\eTABLE


\stoptext
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put a footnote in a table or a frame (created with `\framed` or `\startframedtext`). you have to flush them by hand at the end of the environment/command.

To flush them you can either enclose the table in a `postponingnotes` environment

```
\starttext

Document\footnote{A note in the document}

\startpostponingnotes
\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD
            Table\footnote{A note in the table}
        \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoppostponingnotes

\stoptext
```

or when you have a older installation you can use the `\postponenotes` and `\flushnotes` commands.

```
\starttext

Document\footnote{A note in the document}

\postponenotes
\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD
            Table\footnote{A note in the table}
        \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE
\flushnotes

\stoptext
```

[image: Flush a footnote in a table]

Answer (score 3):

It might be desirable to keep the footnote near the table in case you enclose it in a floating environment.  In this case you can use `\start...\stoplocalfootnotes` together with `\placelocalfootnotes`.  To clearly distinguish the local footnotes from the other document footnotes I set the number conversion to characters.

```
\setuppapersize[A6] % for this showcase only

\starttext

Document\footnote{A note in the document}

\startplacetable[title={Caption}]
  \startlocalfootnotes
    \setupnotation[footnote][numberconversion=characters]
    \bTABLE
      \bTR
        \bTD
          Table\footnote{A note in the table}
        \eTD
      \eTR
    \eTABLE
    \placelocalfootnotes
  \stoplocalfootnotes
\stopplacetable

Document\footnote{Another note in the document}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Henri: why does placing localfootnotes force the table to the left side of the document. How can I get it to be centered again?

Comment: @pdoak See https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086526.html and https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086534.html